# Помогите настроить форму обратной связи на php

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

Вроде бы все, что нужно есть но письма не доходят, возможно попадают в спам, точнее сразу удаляются.

**Как исправить, как сделать, чтобы письма точно дошли? Что нужно дописать?**

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <strong>Ваше имя:</strong><br />
        <input maxlength="30" type="text" name="name" />
        <br />
        <strong>Ваш e-mail (для ответа):</strong><br />
        <input maxlength="30" type="text" name="email" />
        <br />
        <strong>Ваше сообщение:</strong><br />
        <textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="mess"></textarea>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение"/>
        </p>
        </form>



   <?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
if (isset($_POST['mess'])) {$mess = $_POST['mess'];}

$to = "e9228098808@yandex.ru"; /*Укажите ваш адрес электронной почты*/
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251\r\nFrom: <example@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Сообщение с вашего сайта";
$message = "Имя пославшего: $name \nЭлектронный адрес: $email \nСообщение: $mess";
$send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($send == 'true')
{
echo "<b>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!<p>";
echo "<a href='feedback.html'>Нажмите,</a> чтобы вернуться на главную страницу";
}
else 
{
echo "<p><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас не корректно заданы почтовые заголовки

```
Content-type: text/plain; charset = windows-1251 From: <engenes@gmail.com>
```

После каждого почтового заголовка должна идти последовательность из двух символов \r\n (перевод строки в стиле Windows), а у вас заголовки Content-type и From разделяются лишь пробелом. Попробуйте переделать их таким образом

```
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251\r\nFrom: <engenes@gmail.com>";
```

Comment: нет не помогло, неужели без готовой cms нельзя отправлять письма..

Comment: Откуда отправляете? С сервера, с локальной машины (почтовый сервер сами настраивали)? Попробуйте сначала отправить письмо без заголовка и из консоли. Добейтесь, чтобы письма уходили и не попадали в спам без PHP. Если они приходят нормально, можно уже разбираться с PHP-кодом, пока слишком много неизвестных, письма могут браковаться и из-за некорректных настроек SMTP-сервера.

Comment: с компьютера сервер на денвере

Comment: Насколько я помню, Денвер не отправляет письма в сеть, он их складирует на диске, не осуществляя реальной рассылки. Попробуйте перенести свой код на хостинг и попробовать там. Для отправки почты с локальной машины потребуется довольно много телодвижений и, к сожалению, это все-равно закончится папкой спам, так как у вас не будет настроена обратная зона (не привяжете доменное имя). Поэтому почтовые возможности лучше сразу тестировать на хостинге, где почта уже настроена (настройка почты не простое даже для профессионального системного администратора).

Comment: спасибо, щас на хостинг файлы суну посмотрю что получится

Comment: да помогло. на хостинге все отлично работает и в спам не попадает